# Tengo 5 variables, necesito generar un codigo SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*- Hola, es mi primer posteo, espero que me puedan entender claro. -*

Tengo 5 variables las cuales son del tipo Bool. True or False.

Necesito poder generar una sentencia SQL depende los estados de las variables.

Pude generarlo de manera muy extensa, queria saber si hay alguna funcion que me facilite el codigo.

Ej de codigo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bitacora WHERE ";

if(($VL_errores == "true") and ($VL_ingresos == "false") and ($VL_config == "false") and ($VL_pesaje == "false") and ($VL_motores == "false")){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%'";
}

if(($VL_errores == "true") and ($VL_ingresos == "true") and ($VL_config == "false") and ($VL_pesaje == "false") and ($VL_motores == "false")){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%' or codigo LIKE '1%'";
}

if(($VL_errores == "true") and ($VL_ingresos == "true") and ($VL_config == "true") and ($VL_pesaje == "false") and ($VL_motores == "false")){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%' or codigo LIKE '1%' or codigo LIKE '2%'";
}
```

El tema es que tengo que generar 32 lineas de codigos para todas las posibilidades.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que tenes se puede simplificar un poco, pero igual pareceria que vas a necesitar las 32 comparaciones. Como esta escrito ahora no tiene sentido, ya que tu where termina repitiendo clausulas todo el tiempo... (si sigues el codigo te vas a dar cuenta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si las variables son BOOLEANAS.. porque compararlas con true o false???

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bitacora WHERE ";
```

if(($VL_errores  ) and (NOT $VL_ingresos) and (not $VL_config ) and (not $VL_pesaje ) and (not $VL_motores )){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%'";
}

if(($VL_errores ) and ($VL_ingresos ) and (not $VL_config ) and (not $VL_pesaje ) and (not $VL_motores )){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%' or codigo LIKE '1%'";
}

if(($VL_errores ) and ($VL_ingresos ) and ($VL_config ) and (not $VL_pesaje ) and (not $VL_motores )){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%' or codigo LIKE '1%' or codigo LIKE '2%'";
}

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude resolver, les dejo aca la muestra:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bitacora";

if(($VL_errores == "true") || ($VL_ingresos == "true") || ($VL_config == "true") || ($VL_motores == "true") || ($VL_pesaje == "true")){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
}

if($VL_errores == "true"){
    $sql .= "codigo LIKE '0%'";
}
if($VL_ingresos == "true"){
    if($VL_errores == "true"){
        $sql .= " or ";
    }
        $sql .= "codigo LIKE '1%'";
}
if($VL_config == "true"){
    if(($VL_errores == "true") || ($VL_ingresos == "true")){
        $sql .= " or ";
    }
        $sql .= "codigo LIKE '2%'";
}
if($VL_motores == "true"){
    if(($VL_errores == "true") || ($VL_ingresos == "true") || ($VL_config == "true")){
        $sql .= " or ";
    }
        $sql .= "codigo LIKE '3%'";
}
if($VL_pesaje == "true"){
    if(($VL_errores == "true") || ($VL_ingresos == "true") || ($VL_config == "true") || ($VL_motores == "true")){
        $sql .= " or ";
    }
        $sql .= "codigo LIKE '4%'";
}
```